# React frontend + graphene Django backend SPA deployment

Tags: django, reactjs, web-deployment, graphene-django

I want to deploy a SPA on only one VM, with debian 10. What I wanted to do is all routes to go to index.html of my static react app, except `/admin/*` and `/graphql/*` which should lead to the corresponding django pages.
I have tried using Caddy, setting up a reverse proxy for `/admin/*` and `/graphql/*` but I end up with a working frontend and a working admin page (but the style of this page is not loaded for some reason). However, the graphql page does not work at all (blank page) and the frontend cannot make request to the backend.

Do you know how I should do it? I was wondering if I'd rather go with nginx and uWSGI instead of using Caddy, with which I had to use gunicorn, but then I would need help to configure nginx properly. Or maybe the way I wanted to do it is a dead-end and I should totally change it?

Thanks for your help!